# Reset NSTextField's text to empty string -- setText: doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField`, and I need a button to reset the text of the field. How would I do that? I have been trying this:

```
[textBox setText:@""];
textbox.text = @"";
```

That does not work, but I have researched, and found nothing on how to set the text, only how to get the text.

Comment: Have you hooked up the outlet to textBox correctly?

Comment: How does it not work - the first line of code should set the text - to be of more help we need to see more of your code and what you expect

Comment: yes, and also, so i want to set the text of the textbox...it is self explanatory...with C#, i can do this in like 1 second. textbox.text = "tex here";

Comment: Describe what you mean by "does not work". I think you'll find that there's an important clue in the results of the compilation.

Comment: @EliteGamer: Welcome to the world of mac osx. You will be having a lot of trouble, coz very few people are in mac osx development. But it is not too tough, have faith in you and AppleDocumentation. Most of the time google will fail, but not let you to fail. When i started as mac developer, i had similar kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is OSX and NSTextField then use :

```
[textBox setStringValue:@""];
```

Comment: Yes, i got confused whether it is ios or mac osx

Comment: oh, that is fine..Thanks so much! i can accept your answer in like 6 mins

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
theLabel.text = @"this is some text";
[self.view addSubView:theLabel];
```

Here, the label is the text field.